# extract only url segment not the below regular expression in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

### My logic goes here,

```
vodCIntSvc_VideoSegments()
{
# logic to download video segments from mediaPlaylist-Video payload response based on the count

var_param1="#EXTINF:6.006,"

var_segment_cnt=$(echo $var_videoLayer | awk -F"$var_param1" '{print NF}')
echo $var_segment_cnt " count is "
        if [ $input_segment_cnt -le $var_segment_cnt ]; then
                var_segment_cnt=$(($input_segment_cnt+1))
        fi
                i=2
                while [ $i -le $var_segment_cnt ]
                do
                  segment_url=$(echo $var_videoLayer | awk -F"$var_param1" '{print $'$i'}')
                  #"#EXTINF:6.006,
                  echo $segment_url
                  i=$((i+1))
                  echo $segment_url >> /tmp/"$directory_name"/4_videoSegments_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).ts
                done
         echo "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') :: Downloading video segments are successful with argument count- $input_segment_cnt & the output file is saved to :- /tmp/"$directory_name"/4_VideoSegments_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).ts"
}
```

### and the output which I Am getting is :

```
https://manifest.vod.wb4.ott.eng.alticeusa.net/cdn/wb4vodmgmt7idpx01b1.wb4-7.eng.cv.net:5555/hls/NCPHAAAAAOBLNAOF.m3u8/Level(6)/Segment(0).ts **#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES,URI="skd://indemand.com~INMV1019201000659085",KEYFORMAT="com.apple.streamingkeydelivery",KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1",IV=0x0C672EE95BE69AD3AEB30B44A04E966A**
https://manifest.vod.wb4.ott.eng.alticeusa.net/cdn/wb4vodmgmt7idpx01b1.wb4-7.eng.cv.net:5555/hls/NCPHAAAAAOBLNAOF.m3u8/Level(6)/Segment(1).ts **#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES,URI="skd://indemand.com~INMV1019201000659085",KEYFORMAT="com.apple.streamingkeydelivery",KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1",IV=0x0C672EE95BE69AD3AEB30B44A04E966A**
```

the regular expressions `#EXT-X-KEY` for each `url` should be removed

### and the expected output is :

```
https://manifest.vod.wb4.ott.eng.alticeusa.net/cdn/wb4vodmgmt7idpx01b1.wb4-7.eng.cv.net:5555/hls/NCPHAAAAAOBLNAOF.m3u8/Level(6)/Segment(0).ts

https://manifest.vod.wb4.ott.eng.alticeusa.net/cdn/wb4vodmgmt7idpx01b1.wb4-7.eng.cv.net:5555/hls/NCPHAAAAAOBLNAOF.m3u8/Level(6)/Segment(1).ts
```

could someone please provide any suggestions in `shell script` on above my code.

Comment: Probably fix the numerous problems pointed out by http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: Based on you statement "the regular expressions `#EXT-X-KEY` for each `url` should be removed", there is a discrepancy between what you show as the output you're getting and what you show as the desired output in that it's not clear if the space and two asterisks after `... .ts` and before  `#EXT-X-KEY ...` should be removed. Please edit your question to clearify exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way using sed:

```
echo "$segment_url" | sed 's/#EXT-X-KEY.*//'
```

This will remove text starting from `#EXT-X-KEY` till the end of the line.

Comment: yes, you are right, I felt OP's expected answer needs to be corrected because he clearly says everything starting from '#EXP-..' needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try following in awk:

```
echo "$segment_url" | awk '{gsub(/#EXT-X-KEY.*/,"")}1'
```

I used `gsub` here for global substitution you can remove it to sub in case you don't want global substitution here.

Correction 1: `gsub(/#EXT-X-KEY.*/,"")`  added / after *.